# Invalid username/password error django rest framework custom user serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Custom User Model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
         ('R', 'rider'),
         ('D', 'driver'),
    )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ROLE_CHOICES)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    cab = models.OneToOneField('Cab', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

Rider serializer:

```
class RiderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'phone_number', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }
        def create(self, validated_data):
            username = validated_data.pop('username')
            password = validated_data.pop('password')
            instance = User(username, **validated_data)
            if password is not None:
               instance.set_password(password)
               instance.save()
            return instance
```

Rider function based view method:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def rider_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        riders = User.objects.filter(role='R')
        serializer = RiderSerializer(riders, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = RiderSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save(role='R')
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

rider endpoint: /riders/

I am able to create a user object but user authentication fails as password is getting stored as plain text in object.

I have tried using User.objects.create_user(username, password=password, **validated_data) to set password as hashed value but it does not work

I have also tried using make_password method to set hashed password but nothing seems to work.

Please tell me what am i missing. How do i store the hashed password in password field of custom user object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create()` method should be part of serializer class, not part of Meta:

```
class RiderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'phone_number', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        instance = User(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
           instance.set_password(password)
           instance.save()
        return instance
```

Also you don't need to pop `username` field. Just pop password and use it in `set_password` method.